# How do I turn this link_to_function to link_to in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this link_to_function

```
  = link_to_remote 'Populate Info From ID', :url => {:controller => 'something', 
  :action => 'populate_from_id'}, 
  :with => "'id=' + $('account_id').value + '&field_prefix=purchaser'", 
  :update => {:failure => 'account_id_error'}
```

I have converted many of them in a rails upgrade with `, :remote => true, :method => :post`

But i dont know how to add the with condition to grab the value out...any ideas

Answer (score 1):

All the AJAX-specific options representing callbacks are gone in Rails 3 link_to helpers. You'll have to write your own javascript to handle more complex remote actions like your example.

Here's a quick rewrite:

```
# Your template

= link_to 'Populate Info From ID', :url => {:controller => 'something', 
  :action => 'populate_from_id'}, :id => "#populate_info"


# In javascript, assuming jquery and 
# an element #account_id with a data-id attribute
$("#populate_info").on("click", function() {
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    data: { id: $('#account_id').data("id"), field_prefix: "purchaser" }
    error: account_id_error
  });
  return false;
});
```

Useful blog post: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/
Lots of great documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You beat me to it I came up with this

```
$('.populate_id').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
  var failure = $('#' + $(this).attr('failure'));
  failure.html('');
  var element = $('#' + $(this).attr('element'));
  var id = element.val();
  var url_extra = 'account_id=' + id + '&field_prefix=purchaser';
  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: url_extra,
      type: 'post',
      error: function (data) {
        failure.html(data.responseText);
      }
    });
  return false;   
});
```